# Не выполняется код в Python Selenium. В консоле появляется трассировка. Traceback (most recent call last). Какие правки необходимо внести?

Tags: python, selenium, автоматизация

Уважаемые коллеги прошу Вашей помощи.
Выполняю самый простой автотест с использованием Python Selenium.
Должен открыться сайт Youtube в строку поиска необходимо ввести слово "SELENIUM".
На ПК установлен Python.
Через консоль установил Selenium.
Скачал chromedriver.exe и закинул его в папку с мои проектом.
При запуске кода в консоле выдает ошибку.
Я подозревая что не правильно указал какой-то из путей либо не правильно вызываю сам driver.
Первый раз столкнулся с Selenium, не знаю откуда копать, буду благодарен за Вашу помощь

КОД который я пишу

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome('path/chromedriver.exe')

driver.get('https://www.youtube.com/')
seearchbox = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="search"]')
seearchbox.send_keys('SELENIUM')
```

Ошибка после вызова файла с проектом через консоль

```
PS C:\Users\Vadim\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\python> py lesson.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Vadim\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 72, 
in start
    self.process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, env=self.env,
  File "C:\Users\Vadim\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\subprocess.py", line 951, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "C:\Users\Vadim\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\subprocess.py", line 1420, in _execute_child
    hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] Не удается найти указанный файл

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Vadim\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\python\lesson.py", line 2, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome('path/chromedriver.exe')
  File "C:\Users\Vadim\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 73, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "C:\Users\Vadim\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 81, 
in start
    raise WebDriverException(
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver.exe' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home
```

Comment: Судя по ошибке `Message: 'chromedriver.exe' executable needs to be in PATH` у вас неправильный путь до `chromedriver.exe`. Путь `path/chromedriver.exe` относительный или абсолютный? Если относительный, то соответствует ли он активной директории скрипта? Вы можете и не указывать путь до `chromedriver.exe` если укажите его абсолютный путь в переменной окружения `PATH`

Comment: ДА!!! Ошибка была в том что был указан не верный путь к файлу с драйвером. Большое спасибо!

Comment: Пожалуйста :) Оформите решение как собственный ответ ;)